# How can I set authorisation API key and value in request.post() headers in node js

Tags: node.js, header

I have tried following ways to set API key in headers but it still throws an error that API-Token is missing.

```
request.post(
    {
      url: `https://apiURL,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json, charset=utf8',
      1st way: auth: {
                 Key: "Api-Token",
                 Value: "fhfhfh"
                },
      2nd way:  'x-api-key':"Api-Token",
      3rd way:  "apiKey": {
                   "key": "apiKey",
                   "value": "fhfh",
                   "in": "header"
                 }
       4th way:  'Authorization': { key : "API Token",
                    value : "fhghg"}
                 }
       )
```

Comment: Your error states `token is missing` , whether you API is expecting `Bearer token` or something??

Comment: Like we set API Key in authorization in postman when we run our URL like that I need to set that API Key in my request.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    request.get(
    {
      url: 'https://api-url',
      headers: {
        'Api-Token': 'YOUR_API_TOKEN',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json
      }
    }
```